# How to create build.sbt file for Scala projects?

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

I took the following code from GitHub:

```scala
object GraphExample {
  import akka.actor.ActorSystem
  import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
  import akka.stream.scaladsl._
  import FlowGraph.Implicits._
  import scala.util.{ Failure, Success }
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._
    
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("Sys")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val out = Sink.foreach(println)
    
    val g = FlowGraph.closed(out) { implicit builder =>
      sink =>
        val in = Source(1 to 10)
    
        val bcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
        val merge = builder.add(Merge[Int](2))
    
        val f1, f2, f3, f4 = Flow[Int].map(_ + 10)
    
        in ~> f1 ~> bcast ~> f2 ~> merge ~> f3 ~> sink.inlet
        bcast ~> f4 ~> merge
    }.run()
    
    // ensure the output file is closed and the system shutdown upon completion
    g.onComplete {
      case Success(_) =>
        system.shutdown()
      case Failure(e) =>
        println(s"Failure: ${e.getMessage}")
        system.shutdown()
    }
  }
}
```

I want to run this program, but I need a correct **build.sbt** file. I started writing it, and I have:

```scala
name := "Hello Test #1"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
    
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 // to be completed
)
```

My questions are:

1. What lines do I have to write inside `libraryDependency`? The format of each dependency should be: `groupID % artifactID % revision`.
   How do I find these parameters for each import?
2. Do I need other variables inside the **build.sbt** file to make the project run?

Answer (score 1):

If you "found" that code on GitHub, you may as well find the accompanying build file (in sbt, Maven or Gradle supposedly). And that build file should tell you exactly what libraries are used.

From looking at the import clauses, you will want to use the Akka Stream library, in its most recent version that would be:

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.4.9"
```

I don't think you need the Typesafe resolver (the library is on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22akka-stream_2.11%22) which is automatically found by sbt). Note that I use `%%` in front of the artifact-ID, this gives you the major Scala version matching your project. You could also write

```
"com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-stream_2.11" % "2.4.9"
```

since your Scala version is 2.11.x.

Comment: This is the link to GitHub: https://gist.github.com/rocketpages/ed514d309da87711c821#file-streamexample-scala. I didn't find the build.sbt file.

Comment: @CrazySynthax - I see, it's Gist not a GitHub repository. In that case of course you need to guess the library. Seems this is based on the examples in the official Akka docs: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.9/scala/stream/stream-graphs.html

Comment: correct. Do you have a "smart" way to guess the library? My problem is not only guessing the libraries but also guessing the artifactID and revision

Comment: @CrazySynthax No, unfortunately not. Often group and artifact ids are replicated in the Scala package names. Google may help, too.

Comment: Now, I'm only stuck with "  import FlowGraph.Implicits._". Any clue?

Comment: @CrazySynthax perhaps it used an earlier experimental version of Akka Stream. Go check out the link in my first comment, it has essentially the same code ready for current Akka version 2.4.9. You have there instead a `GraphDSL.Implicits._` import.